# Razor DropDownList

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, cultureinfo, selectlist

i want to add a dropdoenlist for months. i want select value like january/february.. i've created a action like this:

```
     public DropDownList  GetMyMonthList()
     {
        DropDownList MyddlMonthList = new DropDownList();
        DateTime month = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2000");
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {

            DateTime NextMont = month.AddMonths(i);
            ListItem list = new ListItem();
            list.Text = NextMont.ToString("MMMM");
            list.Value = NextMont.Month.ToString();
            MyddlMonthList.Items.Add(list);
        }
        return MyddlMonthList;

    }
```

and i called it

```
  ViewBag.months = pm.GetMyMonthList();
```

in my View

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.rent_month,new    SelectList(ViewBag.months          as        System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Text","value"),
        "Select Month")
```

it gives error **Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items**

i'm may be doing a silly mistake. i'm very new in asp.net mvc3. please indicate me my mistake.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the error message, what's happening is that the cast from *DropDownList* to *IEnumerable* is failing silently by returning a null.  I'd suggest changing *GetMyMonthList* to return *IEnumerable<*, and then pass that directly into your constructor for *SelectList*.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetMyMonthList()
{
    var MyddlMonthList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    DateTime month = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2000");
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        DateTime NextMont = month.AddMonths(i);
        var list = new SelectListItem();
        list.Text = NextMont.ToString("MMMM");
        list.Value = NextMont.ToString("MMMM");
        MyddlMonthList.Add(list);
    }
    return MyddlMonthList;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also get the month names from CultureInfo.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetMyMonthList()
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
        .Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m, Value = m });
}
```

Comment: thanks its working. but what will the data of select list after selected?

Comment: it gives value like for february it gives 2. is there any change of this code can give me value like february??????

Comment: Gotcha ... see my edit.  You can get the month names from **System.Globalization.CultureInfo**.